# Observer for Navigator route changes in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to listen to route changes of the Navigator in Flutter? Basically, I'd like to be notified when a route is pushed or popped, and have the current route on display on screen be returned from the notification

Answer (score 10):

Building on navigator observers, you can also use [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) and [RouteAware](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html).

Answer (score 6):

Navigator has [observers](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/observers.html). You can implement [NavigatorObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html) and receive notifications with details.

Answer (score 3):

I was also struggling with that and for my purpose the `RouteObservers` felt overkill and were too much for my needs. The way I handled it lately was to use the `onGenerateRoute` property inside my `MaterialApp`. So this solution is more applicable if you are using `onGenerateRoute` with your app (might especially be useful if you are navigating with arguments). You can read more about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

My `MaterialApp` looks like the following:

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
        title: 'bla',
        home: BuilderPage(LoginArguments(false)),
        onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
));
```

The `generateRoute` method looks like the following:

```dart
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case 'main':
      print('Navigated to main')
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen());
    case 'register':
      print('Navigated to register')
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterScreen());
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                    child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
              ));
  }
}
```

So everytime I now do for example:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        'register',
      );
```

It will print `Navigated to register`. I think this way is especially helpful if you don't necessarily need to know whether you `pushed` or `popped`. With some additional implementation it would also be possible to observe that via injected arguments.

Comment: have you found a way to detect a pop? the generateRoute doesn't look like it does...

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [auto_router](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)

```dart
class LoggingNavigationObserver extends AutoRouterObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    print('Current Screen push: ${route.settings.name}');

  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    //print('Current Screen pop: ${route.settings.name}');
    
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
    print('Current Screen replace: ${newRoute?.settings.name}');
   
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didRemove(route, previousRoute);
    print('Current Screen remove: ${route.settings.name}');
  
  }

  @override
  void didChangeTabRoute(TabPageRoute route, TabPageRoute? previousRoute) {
    // Handle tab route change in the navigator
    print('Tab route changed: ${route.name}');
   
  }

 
}
```

default flutter router [source](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/tracking-screen-transition-by-route-observer-flutter-dadd8773699c)

```dart
class MyRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  void _sendScreenView(PageRoute<dynamic> route) {
    var screenName = route.settings.name;
    print('screenName $screenName');
    // do something with it, ie. send it to your analytics service collector
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    if (route is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(route);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic> newRoute, Route<dynamic> oldRoute}) {
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
    if (newRoute is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(newRoute);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (previousRoute is PageRoute && route is PageRoute) {
      _sendScreenView(previousRoute);
    }
  }
}
```

Register your observers as usual and you should be good to go.