# Call function every page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a many pages and I want to check every time this page call, if JWT TOKEN is expired.
Do I have to call this function in every page or can I for example insert it only in the main.dart?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen/observ to the naviation : [Observer for Navigator route changes in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541225/observer-for-navigator-route-changes-in-flutter)

And excecute you JWT token check method there.